# iOS 8 Using external GPS

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, gps

I am currently working on an external bluetooth GPS (Garmin Glo)(MFi approved) for iPhone.

Once it is get connected. I tried to use EAAccessory framework to read the NMEA data, I only get 15 bytes incoming data then no more stream data come in.

I am wondering if iOS already forwarded all the data to the CLLocationManager?

If the external GPS is connected, the location data I get via CLLocationManager is from internal GPS or external GPS?

I would appreciate if someone can explain me the logic behind. Thanks!

Comment: CLLocationMan always takes the internal GPS. I doubt that ios will consume the bytes from the stream. Most probably you made an error in the communication set up-

Comment: @AlexWien Thank you for the reply.  I run my app on a iPad which does not have an internal gps and airplane mode is on , but it connects to the external gps(Garmin Glo). My app record the route very nicely. Would it be CLLocationManager automatically turn to use external gps data?

Comment: @AlexWien As for the setup, I guess it goes correctly since the nsinputstream does not have any coming bytes to read. I also download the EADemo from apple, it shows the received data 15 bytes also.

Comment: And who tells that the GPS chip is set up correctly? Baud rate? NMEA mode, binary mode, etc? Connext the gps first to an PC application like uCenter from ublox. Then you can see what the chip sends. And if NMEA is enabled, etc.

Comment: bye the way, why do you want to connect to an external GPS device?

Comment: I have the android version shows data from the external GPS, all the data sends correctly.  With the iPad test, I think it sends the data to iPad correctly also.  The point is I am not sure which GPS data source it takes, when my app is running on the iPhone.

Comment: Why I use the external gps, it gives 10 samples per second.

Comment: I heavily doubt that ios would use the external GPS for the CLLocationman. The NMEA has many dialects, it is not well specified, each GPS manufactrer provide a 30-60 pages manual how the NMEA format is delivered by that specific chip. Apple for sure cannot suppoort all known and unknown NMEA dialects. And they don't want to make their system instable by relying on external devices. When you found out more, please post it at a self answer.

Comment: @AlexWien I will do that . Thank you for the discussion.

Comment: Were you ever able to get connecting to the Garmin GLO working using the ExternalAccessory framework? If so, what protocol string did you use?

Comment: @AlexWien I think it *is* possible for CLLocationManager to automatically use external GPS data from an Apple approved MFI External Accessory device.   This product apparently can do it ( I have not tried it ): http://amanenterprises.com/nmea-bt-2/

Comment: @Ed. Yes you are right, altough not all GPS devices would work via this dongle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting external GPS serial-to-Bluetooth product.  I have no association with this device or company, only in interest in iOS development and GPS.

[Aman Enterprises - NMEA-BT](http://amanenterprises.com/nmea-bt-2/)

- It is an Apple MFI certified Bluetooth dongle that connects to NMEA
  GPS via serial
- No jailbreak required.
- No iOS special iOS app required to use it since it injects data into the iOS devices Core Location API.

[FAQ](http://amanenterprises.com/faq/)

> Q: What apps can I use with the cable?
>
> A: The GPS Cable provides data
> to an iOS app using the Core Location API. Since the Core Location API
> is the standard way that a location aware iOS app obtains positioning
> data, the cable is expected to work any location aware iOS app.

I am interested in learning how it works as I have an experimental app that parses NMEA strings from a Bluetooth External Accessory.

Is it possible for an iOS app to override Core Location API to become the Core Location provides for all apps installed on the device?